# List Iterator from STL library malfunctioning

Tags: c++, stl

The following is a snippet of a larger program and is done using Pthreads.

The UpdateFunction reads from a text file. The FunctionMap is just used to output (key,1). Here essentially UpdateFunction and FunctionMap run on different threads.

```
queue <list<string>::iterator> mapperpool;

void *UpdaterFunction(void* fn) {
    std::string *x = static_cast<std::string*>(fn);
    string filename = *x;
    ifstream file (filename.c_str());
    string word;
    list <string> letterwords[50];
    char alphabet = '0';
    bool times = true;

    int charno=0;

    while(file >> word) {
        if(times) {
            alphabet = *(word.begin());
            times = false;
        }
        if (alphabet != *(word.begin())) {
            alphabet = *(word.begin());
            mapperpool.push(letterwords[charno].begin());
            letterwords[charno].push_back("xyzzyspoon");
            charno++;
        }
        letterwords[charno].push_back(word);
    }

    file.close();

    cout << "UPDATER DONE!!" << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *FunctionMap(void *i) {
    long num = (long)i;
    stringstream updaterword;
    string toQ;
    int charno = 0;


    fprintf(stderr, "Print me %ld\n", num);
    sleep(1);

    while (!mapperpool.empty()) {
        list<string>::iterator it = mapperpool.front();
        while(*it != "xyzzyspoon") {
            cout << "(" << *it << ",1)" << "\n";
            cout << *it << "\n";
            it++;   
        }
        mapperpool.pop();
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

If I add the while(!mapperpool.empty()) in the UpdateFunction then it gives me the perfect output. But when I move it back to the FunctionMap then it gives me a weird out and Segfaults later.
Output when used in UpdateFunction:
Print me 0
course
cap
class
culture
class
cap
course
course
cap
culture
concurrency
.....

[Each word in separate line]

Output when used in FunctionMap (snippet shown above):
Print me 0
UPDATER DONE!!
(course%0+�0@+�0�+�05P+�0����cap%�+�0�+�0,�05�+�0����class5P?�0
����xyzzyspoon%�+�0�+�0(+�0%P,�0`,�0�,�05+�0����class%p,�0�,�0-�05�,�0����cap%�,�0�,�0X-�05�,�0����course%-�0 -�0�-�050-�0����course%`-�0p-�0�-�05�-�0����cap%�-�0�-�0H.�05�-�0����culture%.�0.�0�.�05 .�0
                                                        ����concurrency%P.�0`.�0�.�05p.�0����course%�.�0�.�08/�05�.�0����cap%�.�0/�0�/�05/�0Segmentation fault (core dumped)

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: `while(*it != "xyzzyspoon") it++` This is very suspicious. You need to check somehow for the end of the list. Who guarantees that the list contains the specified string?

Comment: The list definitely does not contain that string. And even if it does, I should atleast get the first few characters correctly which I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list <string> letterwords[50]` is local to `UpdaterFunction`. When `UpdaterFunction` finishes, all its local variables got destroyed. When `FunctionMap` inspects iterator, that iterator already points to deleted memory.
When you insert `while(!mapperpool.empty())` `UpdaterFunction` waits for `FunctionMap` completion and `letterwords` stays 'alive'.

Answer (score 1):

> Here essentially UpdateFunction and FunctionMap run on different threads.

And since they both manipulate the same object (`mapperpool`) and neither of them uses either [pthread_mutex](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) nor [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) (C++11), you have a data race. If you have a data race, you have Undefined Behaviour and the program might do whatever it wants. Most likely it will write garbage all over memory until eventually crashing, exactly as you see.

> How do I fix this issue?

By locking the `mapperpool` object.

**Why is list not thread-safe?**

Well, in vast majority of use-cases, a single list (or any other collection) won't be used by more than one thread. In significant part of the rest the lock will have to extend over more than one operation on the collection, so the client will have to do its own locking anyway. The remaining tiny percentage of cases where locking in the operations themselves would help is not worth adding the overhead for everyone; C++ key design principle is that you only pay for what you use.

The collections are only *reentrant*, meaning that using *different* instances in parallel is safe.

**Note on pthreads**

C++11 introduced [threading library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) that integrates well with the language. Most notably, it uses RAII for locking of [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) via [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), [std::unique_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and [std::shared_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) (for reader-writer locking). Consistently using these can eliminate large class of locking bugs that otherwise take considerable time to debug.

If you can't use C++11 yet (on desktop you can, but some embedded platforms did not get a compiler update yet), you should first consider [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread.html) as it provides the same benefits.

If you can't use even then, still try to find, or write, a simple [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) wrapper for locking like the C++11/Boost do. The basic wrapper is just a couple of lines, but it will save you a lot of debugging.

Note that [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) and [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/atomic.html) also have *atomic* operations library that pthreads sorely miss.

Comment: Was a great answer! Thanks! This was a class assignment. The main goal of the assignment was to make the students try the Pthreads library.